# my function keeps checking the same index instead of checking the other index

Tags: python, list

```
def capital_indexes(word):
    letters = []

    capital_letters = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']

    index_letters = []

    # append letters in the word to a list
    for letter in word:
        letters.append(letter)

    # go through the letters in the list letters
    for i in letters:
        # checks if the indexes in the list match with the indexes in the list 'capital_leters'
        if i in capital_letters:
            index_letters.append(word.index(i))

    return index_letters


word_capital = capital_indexes('TEsT')
# this should return (0, 1, 3) but it keeps returning (0, 1, 0)

print(word_capital)
```

Comment: by somehow is this leetcode today's problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.index` returns the first occurrence of a letter, use `enumerate` and `.isupper`:

```
def capital_indexes(word):
    return [i for i,l in enumerate(word) if l.isupper()]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is highly inefficient, for instance the conversion to list is useless (you can iterate over a string), then looping through all capital letters is also inefficient (rather use a set). Finally, your main error resides in the fact that `word.index(i)` will always return the position of the **first** match (thus the 0 in place of 3).

Here is an alternative solution:

```
def capital_indexes(word):
    # general case for any given set of characters
    from string import ascii_uppercase
    letters = set(ascii_uppercase)
    return [i for i,c in enumerate(word) if c in letters]
    # case for uppercase only
    # return [i for i,c in enumerate(word) if c.isupper()]
        
capital_indexes('TEsT')
# [0, 1, 3]
```

Comment: "the conversion to list is useless (you can iterate over a string" - Looks like they already know that, as they're iterating over the string to do the conversion :-)

Comment: @Kelly in `for i in letters:`, `letters` is a list

Comment: Not sure why you're saying that. In `for letter in word:`, `word` is a string

Comment: Well, they should do that directly when testing the characters, building the list is useless

Answer (score 0):

This is because T is at index 0 and index 3, so index 0 is returned twice.

Try:

```py
import string

result = [i for i, char in enumerate(word) if char in string.ascii_uppercase]
```

In your example:

```py
>>> word = "TEsT"
>>> [i for i, char in enumerate(word) if char in string.ascii_uppercase]

[0, 1, 3]
```

Comment: rather use a set (see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70833744/16343464)), repeatedly searching for a character in a string is costly

Comment: Fair point, on average it is constant time for a set - https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity. However the list is small and fixed here so not too important.

Comment: Well, this was not the worst in the original code, but still, this is a good practice. An important thing in coding is also trying to learn optimization to be ready to use is with production code ;)

Comment: @mozway Or `'A' <= char <= 'Z'`. Not sure what's faster...

Comment: @Kelly the double comparison is ~60% slower than set indexing

Comment: @mozway For what characters? Maybe `char <= 'Z' and char >= 'A'` instead?

Comment: seems general (tested a few), same with your new comparison